# Use scikit-learn TfIdf with gensim LDA

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-mining, lda

I've used various versions of TFIDF in scikit learn to model some text data.

```
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df=1,stop_words='english')
```

The resulting data X is in this format:

```
<rowsxcolumns sparse matrix of type '<type 'numpy.float64'>'
    with xyz stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

I wanted to experiment with LDA as a way to do reduce dimensionality of my sparse matrix.
Is there a simple way to feed the NumPy sparse matrix X into a gensim LDA model?

```
lda = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=100)
```

I can ignore scikit and go the way the gensim tutorial outlines, but I like the simplicity of the scikit vectorizers and all of its parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/matutils.html

```
class gensim.matutils.Sparse2Corpus(sparse, documents_columns=True)

      Convert a matrix in scipy.sparse format into a streaming gensim corpus.
```