# Can we predict new corpus using trained LDA model?

Tags: python-3.6, gensim, lda, topic-modeling

I have trained LDA model on 2000 URL's(containing articles) on a particular topic in Python3. Can we predict new corpus based on the trained model?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your dictionary is named as `dic_1` and `new_corpus` is collections of documents.

We first create a gensim corpus by following:

```py
corpus_1= [dic_1.doc2bow(tokenize(doc)) for doc in new_corpus ]
```

Now we can make prediction using trained model by following:

```py
new_predictions= LDA[corpus_1]
```

Comment: I printed "print(model[corpus3])", gives me output 
<gensim.interfaces.TransformedCorpus object at 0x0000020B19BF12E8>


How to read the output to make sense out of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19504898/use-s%D1%81ikit-learn-tfidf-with-gensim-lda?answertab=active#tab-top

With reference tothe above link: I am able to convert matrix in scipy.sparse format into a streaming gensim corpus. But while  training into lda = models.ldamodel.LdaModel(corpus=new_corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=100), What will be the dictionary used here? As dictionary for tfidf would be different - how is that generated?

Comment: Do you want to train another model using "new_corpus" ?  Please elaborate more about what you want to achieve as right now its confusing.

Comment: I tried to use Tfidf on my training set & want to feed into my LDA model. While doing that I am able to convert the tfidf matrix into gensim corpus by using
**gensim.matutils.Sparse2Corpus(tfidf_matrix,documents_columns=False)**


But while passing it into the LDA model, should I use vectorize.vocabulary_ as my dictionary or what else can be used as dictionary? 

How can I improve my model because the accuracy is not good at all?

Comment: Atendra : 
the code mentioned above 
corpus_1= [dic_1.doc2bow(tokenize(doc)) for docin new_corpus ]

here corpus_1- is the new corpus formed by New article.
dic_1 is the dictionary created for new corpus?
new_corpus : is old corpus of our trained model?
what is doc here ? Is it our training dataset?